# What Does Rows_examined Mean Exactl in MySql

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, rdbms

Is row_examined mean only examine the PK Index (the index column)? or else all row data is getting examined?

I am having a table with a PK and and UNIQUE KEY

```
   show index from  test_table;
+-----------------+------------+----------------+--------------+--------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+    
| Table           | Non_unique | Key_name       | Seq_in_index | Column_name        | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-----------------+------------+----------------+--------------+--------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| test_table      |          0 | PRIMARY        |            1 | test_table_PK      | A         |      105464 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| test_table      |          0 | test_table_UNQ |            1 | test_table_UNQ     | A         |      105464 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+-----------------+------------+----------------+--------------+--------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

**EXPLAIN select * from test_table  group by test_table_PK limit 70000,10 ;**

result:

```
         id: 1
select_type: SIMPLE
      table: test_table
       type: index
possible_keys: NULL
      key: PRIMARY
  key_len: 8
      ref: NULL
     rows: 70010
    Extra:
```

My question is:

in the above query result why the possible_keys is null ? even the table contains two key.

why mysql examined 70010 records?

and how do I reduce the count of rows_examined?

below is the actual query which taking around 13 sec to execute.

```
EXPLAIN EXTENDED select * from test_table

LEFT JOIN rel_test_table_1

ON 
     test_table.test_table_PK = rel_test_table_1.test_table_PK
LEFT JOIN test_table_2
ON 
    rel_test_table_1.test_table_2_PK= test_table_2.test_table_2_PK
LEFT JOIN rel_test_table_2
ON
     test_table_2.test_table_2_PK = rel_test_table_2.test_table_2_PK
LEFT JOIN test_table_3
ON 
    rel_test_table_2.test_table_3_PK = test_table_3.test_table_3_PK 
limit 70000,10\G
```

Query Result
    *************************** 1. row ***************************

```
       id: 1
select_type: SIMPLE
    table: test_table
     type: ALL
possible_keys: NULL
      key: NULL
  key_len: NULL
      ref: NULL
     rows: 105578
  filtered: 100.00
    Extra:
```

*************************** 2. row ***************************

```
       id: 1
 select_type: SIMPLE
    table: rel_test_table_1
     type: eq_ref
 possible_keys: test_table_PK,rel_test_table_1_FK1_IDX
      key: test_table_PK
  key_len: 8
      ref: db2486db.test_table.test_table_PK
     rows: 1
 filtered: 100.00
    Extra:
```

*************************** 3. row ***************************

```
       id: 1
 select_type: SIMPLE
    table: test_table_2
     type: eq_ref
 possible_keys: PRIMARY
      key: PRIMARY
  key_len: 8
      ref: db2486db.rel_test_table_1.test_table_2_PK
     rows: 1
 filtered: 100.00
    Extra:
```

*************************** 4. row ***************************

```
       id: 1
 select_type: SIMPLE
    table: rel_test_table_2
     type: ref
 possible_keys: PRIMARY,test_table_PK,rel_test_table_2_FK1_IDX
      key: PRIMARY
  key_len: 8
      ref: db2486db.test_table.test_table_PK
     rows: 1
 filtered: 100.00
    Extra: Using index
```

*************************** 5. row ***************************

```
       id: 1
 select_type: SIMPLE
    table: test_table_3
     type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY
      key: PRIMARY
  key_len: 8
      ref: db2486db.rel_test_table_2.test_table_PK
     rows: 1
 filtered: 100.00
    Extra:
```

Comment: from [this page](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/07/24/mysql-explain-limits-and-errors/) limit is not taking into account in "rows" column of EXPORT. but that is not important here. your query is slow?

Comment: when I add 6 or 7 left joins, its take 13 to 14 sec to execute the query, which is relatively too slow.

Comment: why did you then only show explain with only 1 table. put EXPLAIN for full select query you use. problem is probably with some index missing in one of the tables.

Comment: it can also happen that type(or size) of columns you use to join tables are not the same, so that could slow query.

Comment: all reference columns are type of bigint(19)

Comment: test_table doesnt seem to have any INDEX. Are you sure you have one? Btw can you put SHOW CREATE Table(s) here.

Comment: @BojanKovacevic I have added show index for the table.

Comment: `EXPLAIN select * from test_table group by test_table_PK limit 70000,10` - how could an index be used here? Read the query. You asked for everything grouped by a column. Do you think indexes are magic things that you set and that make things go faster? The second query is the same, there is no condition that can use indexes. `LIMIT` clause does not utilise indexes (it can't). Offsetting by 70k doesn't use indexes (it can't). To know the record that's at 70k, you need to select 70k to *count* it.

Comment: can you set up [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) with sample data. As N.B said you dont have some filters (WHERE clause) that would use indexes but still 14sec seems too slow.

Comment: @BojanKovacevic - there was no mention of storage engine used or its configuration. If it's MyISAM or default config of InnoDB running on slow hdd, then the performance isn't that surprising.